# How can we determine where the relationship is not linear anymore?

Tags: regression, python, matlab

My data look like the following figure. I want to figure out at which point the relationship between y and x starts to become linear. Let’s call this point $x_0$.  Let me divide my question into three parts.

Part 1: I know that the slope of the line approaches the exact value when x goes to infinity. My idea is to fit a line for the data points where $x$ is very large. Then find the confidence interval at each x right to $x_0$ and if $y$ at that point is outside the confidence interval, call that point $x_0$. Am I right?

Part 2: How much does it matter whether or not we know the slope of the line approaches the exact value when x goes to infinity?

Part 3: How can I implement it using MATLAB or Python considering the fact that $n$ in a linear regression changes when we add a new point?

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 0):

Common problem. Search for segmented regression. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python) for an example.

Comment: It might be nice to say a little bit more about what the technique does?  As written, this is more of a comment than a full-blown answer ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382903/how-to-apply-piecewise-linear-fit-in-python

Comment: Thank you. The link talks about piecewise linear regression, which to my understanding fits piecewise lines to different parts of the graph. From theory, I know when x is large enough the curve approaches a line. For small values of x, there is no specific trend, so I doubt that fitting a line or a curve for small values of x is a good idea. I am trying to find a "scientific way" to determine when the curve "significantly" deviates from the line. My question is how to figure out what this "significantly" means. This is important for me because the breaking point has a scientific meaning.